# Sonar ThreadGroup error on IllegalArgumentException

Tags: sonarqube, illegalargumentexception, threadgroup

Sonar shows "ThreadGroup" error on the line where IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
Why is the issue here?
[image]

Here is the code snippet, where issue is found by Sonar:

```
public static ResolutionElection fromValue(String value) {
    for (ResolutionElection election : ResolutionElection.values()) {
        if (election.getValue().equals(value)) {
            return election;
        }
    }
    throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Sonar error description:

> Avoid Thread Group
>   Avoid using ThreadGroup; although it is intended to
>   be used in a threaded environment it contains methods that are not
>   thread safe.

Comment: Can you precise the key of the rule ? as well as a code snippet of where the issue occurs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue relating to underlying analyzer PMD : 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPMD-5

As per this [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1018/), this bug should be fix if you use latest version of sonar-pmd plugin (2.2 as of writing) which relies on PMD 5.1.1